# Gradle binary dependency without extension?

Tags: gradle

Is it possible in gradle to have a binary dependency without extension? We are developing in java but we execute some native applications (that be package) in linux/win/mac, and we are starting to manage them with gradle. The general solution works fine, but I cannot convince gradle that the linux and mac artifacts have no extension. For windows we have:

```
dependencies {
    myArchives(group: myGroupId, name: myArtifactId, version: myVersion, classifier: 'windows', ext: 'exe')
}
```

For linux and mac I was expecting not declaring 'ext' would do the trick but it goes to '.jar' by default. Setting it to the empty string doesn't work either.

Is there a way of achieving it?